# cat file with no line wrap

Tags: linux, unix, shell

In *nix, how do I display (cat) a file with no line-wrapping: longer lines should be cut such that they fit into screen's width.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Note that `cut` accepts a filename as an argument.

This seems to work for me:

```
watch 'bash -c "cut -c -$COLUMNS file"'
```

For testing, I added a right margin:

```
watch 'bash -c "cut -c -$(($COLUMNS-10)) file"'
```

When I resized my terminal, the truncation was updated to match.

Comment: When I run your script `watch ./colscript`, I see 80 displayed. When I change the width by dragging the edge of the window (I'm using PuTTY) the number changes to match. What do you see?

Comment: I see nothing, but I figured out why: different bash versions.


watch ./colscript works on bash 4.0 (my computer), but not on bash 3.0 (a remote computer).

./colscript doesn't work on any of the two versions.

Comment: `echo $BASH_VERSION` gives me "3.2.48(1)-release" The reason that running `./colscript` from the command line echoes a blank line is that `$COLUMNS` is only populated for interactive shells. You can try added `-i` at the end of the first line of `./colscript` so you have `#!/bin/bash -i`

Answer (score 58):

You may be looking for [`fmt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fmt):

```
fmt file
```

This pretty aggressively reformats your text, so it may do more than what you want.

Alternatively, the `cut` command can cut text to a specific column width, discarding text beyond the right margin:

```
cat file | cut -c1-80
```

Another handy option is the `less -S` command, which displays a file in a full screen window with left/right scrolling for long lines:

```
less -S file
```

Comment: Indeed, it does more than I want: it concatenates lines.

Comment: Actually, I'm watching the content of the file using watch "cat file" so I can't use less.

cat file | cut -c1-80 did the trick, partially. Any way to adjust the cut to the screen size?

Comment: You may have the environment variable `$COLUMNS` defined: try
`cut -c1-$COLUMNS file`

Comment: You can use watch like: `watch "cat file | cut -c1-$COLUMNS"` so the pipe is executed by watch (without the quotes then `cut` will be cutting the output of `watch` which is probably not going to work well).

Comment: $COLUMNS doesn't work inside a shell script, any alternative?

Comment: `stty -a` on my system prints the number of columns on the first line. So try: `stty -a|head -1|awk '{print $6}'`

Comment: Cool. The "less -S" version is pretty awesome.

Comment: @Alexandru, this should be best answer.

Comment: You can toggle wrapping while `less` is running using the key combination `-S`

Answer (score 8):

as stated by others, the answer is `cut -c ...`, but to add some dynamic to it, I prefer this:

`cat file.txt |cut -c -$(tput cols)`

Comment: this limits the output to a specified (but dynamic) columns length

Answer (score 4):

to toggle long-line-wrap in less. Default is to wrap.

```
- `less file`
- in file type `"-S"` to toggle to truncate on line width
- to toggle back `"-S"` again.
```

Comment: You can also call `less` with `-S` as an option: `less -S file` or include it in your environment: `export LESS="-S"` (plus other options). In either case, you can still use the toggle once it's running if you want.

Answer (score 3):

The use of `cut` does not take into account that tabs are considered a single character `\t` but they are printed as 8 blank spaces. Thus a file with tabs will be cut at different perceived columns.

`less -S` truncates optimally the text, also in the presence of tabs, but AFAIK it cannot be used to non-interactively print the "chopped" file.

A working solution is to convert tabs into spaces through `expand` and then `cut` the output: 
    `expand < file | cut -c -$(tput cols)`

Comment: `expand` is a great help; thanks, I was just wrestling with this issue (with tabs). Glad I scrolled to the bottom!

Answer (score 0):

Other solution, this time using paginate command `pr`

`echo "your long line" | pr -m -t -w 80`