# Perl print function word wrap

Tags: perl, unix, printing, word-wrap

How is it possible to print output to console with `print` function **without** wordwrap? It seems that automatically it wraps the long words.

I'm trying to write some easy text viewer so I need your hints :)
Should different function be used or some mode changed?

Comment: Have a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616404/cat-file-with-no-line-wrap

Comment: The `print` function isn't doing the wrapping; your console is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is less perl, more unix. Perl doesn't wrap lines, your terminal is doing so.

However, I'd start with something like `Term::ReadKey` which can use `GetTerminalSize();`

And then use that to format my 'print' statements.

e.g.

```
use Term::ReadKey;
my ( $width_chars ) = GetTerminalSize();
```

And then use that to truncate the line, probably using `substr`.

E.g.

```
print substr ( $line, 0, $width_chars ),"\n"
```